# Changing type from entity when passing as parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm attempting to change the type of the Entity. I'm calling a function with requires 2 parameters, 1 is the entity and the other is a location. Although when I attempt to pass a Type for the first entity is gives me this error:

```
Argument of type 'Node<EntityBasic>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node<AlertBasic>'.
  Type 'EntityBasic' is not assignable to type 'AlertBasic'.
    Property 'id' is optional in type 'EntityBasic' but required in type 'AlertBasic'.
```

This is the function:

```
public async func() {
 const entBasic: EntityBasic = this.getEntity(entity);
 const NEO4J_TYPE = entType === 'alert' ? 'Alert' : 'Guide';

 const entNode = await this.neo4jService.createOrUpdate<EntityBasic>(
      NEO4J_TYPE,
      entBasic.id,
      entBasic,
    );

 if (NEO4J_TYPE === 'Alert')
      await this.calendarEventsSyncService.handleEvents(entNode, location); 
}
```

I need to change the entNode from EntityBasic to AlertBasic

 I have attempted to:

```
if (NEO4J_TYPE === 'Alert')
      await this.calendarEventsSyncService.handleEvents(entNode: AlertBasic, location);
```

But I get a `Expected 2 parameter instead of 3`

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can only use `entNode: AlertBasic` to declare a function signature. Not when calling a function, which is what you are doing.

```
if (NEO4J_TYPE === 'Alert')
      await this.calendarEventsSyncService.handleEvents(entNode: AlertBasic, location);
```

There are several ways to handle this and which is appropriate really depends on the larger system.

**A risky solution: use as**

You can use **as** to tell TypeScript to pretend one type to be another. This could lead to issues, since you are introducing a lie into your system.

```
if (NEO4J_TYPE === 'Alert')
      await this.calendarEventsSyncService.handleEvents(entNode as Node<AlertBasic>, location);
```

**transform the type beforehand**

You may want to transform one type to another using a function. With a signature like:

```
function transform_AlertBasic_toEntityBasic( alert_basic: AlertBasic ): EntityBasic {
   // ... some code that makes the transformation
}
```

**check if there is a supertype**

There may be a superclass that covers an API for both types you can use.

Comment: this is the `handleEvents: public async handleEvents(     alertNode: Neode.Node<AlertBasic>,     loc: Neo4jLocation,   ): Promise<void> {` I can't seem to use Node<AlertBasic> it gives me a Type 'Node' is not generic.t

Answer (score 1):

You can cast `entNode` to `Node<AlertBasic>`:

```
 await this.calendarEventsSyncService.handleEvents(entNode as Node<AlertBasic>, location);
```

or in case of interface confict between `AlertBasic` and `EntityBasic`:

```
 await this.calendarEventsSyncService.handleEvents(entNode as unknown as Node<AlertBasic>, location);
```

Comment: It worked, although I got this: `Argument of type 'AlertBasic' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node<AlertBasic>'.
  Type 'AlertBasic' is missing the following properties from type 'Node<AlertBasic>': model, idInt, get, properties, and 4 more`

Comment: @NiltonSchumacherF I edited my answer, now it should be ok. Sorry, I didn't notice you need to pass `Node` generic instead of `AlertBasic` itself.

Comment: No problem, I got that `Type NODE is not generic now` so strange

Comment: @NiltonSchumacherF it's really strange, can you share updated code somewhere? Incude `handleEvents` method if possible

Comment: this is the handleEvents: `public async handleEvents(
    alertNode: Neode.Node<AlertBasic>,
    loc: Neo4jLocation,
  ): Promise<void> {`